# How to change namespace name in an asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net

How to change the namespace name in an asp.net webform
For example in my project i have created 3 folders Master,Transaction,Reports in Master folder there are 10 forms by default th namespace comes ProjectName.Master,but when i manually change the name by adding my formname it doesn't work eg:-ProjectName.Master.MasterFormName.And moreover when i double click on a button then it doesn't go in the code behind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing a namespace in c# code alone isn't sufficient.
You also need to tell your .master file what class it inherits from.
Set the new namespace in you .master file and you will be good to go.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ProjectName.Master.cs"   
    Inherits="ProjectName.Master.MasterFormName.MasterFormName" %>
```

Just my personal opinion: putting your class name in the namespace doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Now i added a new name eg:-my previous namespace was ProjectName.Master.MasterFormName now i changed it to ProjectName.Master.Mstfrmnm.MasterFormName and in inherits i wrote Mstfrmnm before MasterFormName it worked thanks a lot nunespascal

Comment: if the solution worked for you, do accept it by clicking the tick at the top left of the answer